# Converting CHAR to NUM with varying decimal places

Tags: sas

I am trying to convert a column stored from character to numeric. The problem is that this column has varying number of decimal places.

For example,

```
 Data
 1052969525
 392282764.234
 221018301.2
 130010764.7894
 82340150
 183779233.4
```

I have determined that the likely maximum of decimal places is 4, the width required would be about 15. So I have attempted the following:

```
 datanum = input(data, 15.4);
```

But this appears to put the decimal place in the wrong place, especially for those that have no decimal places. What is the most reasonable way to convert this column from char to numeric? This column is part of a database table uploaded by someone else so there's not much option to change that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't normally supply the decimal width in informats.  For a normal number, you only supply the width, and SAS will figure out the decimal for you (based on the position of the decimal point).

```
datanum = input(data,15.);
```

The `.d` part of an informat is to allow for compatibility with (mostly) older systems that did not have decimals in the data, to save space.  For example, if I'm reading in money amounts, and I only have 6 spaces:

```
123456
882348
100000
123400
```

I can read that in as an integer amount of cents - or I can do:

```
input cost 6.2;
```

That will then tell SAS to place the decimal before the last 2 characters.